# Select expression with conditions and alias

Tags: php, mysql, yii

In MySql you can have a query like this

```
SELECT d., d.is_new, 
      ( 
        d.distance - 1 
      ) AS `dist` 
FROM `table` AS d
WHERE d.is_new!='1' 
HAVING `dist` <= 10
```

How do i make this work in Yii 1.1.15 using my **scopes function** in my model? Right now i have this

```
public function scopes()
    {
        return array(
            '_distance'=>array(
                    'alias' => 'd',
                    'select'=>array('d.id, d.is_new, 
                                        ( 
                                            d.distance - 1 
                                        ) AS `dist`'
                                    ),
                    'having'=>'`dist` <= 10',
                    'condition'=>'d.is_new!="1"'
                )
        );
    }
```

Query works, it just doesn't return the `dist` column when i call `_distance`. When i run the query in phpmyadmin it works fine too.

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider(Bla::model()->_distance(), ..... );
```

Any idea what i'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a public $dist property in your Active Record class.

When an Active Record find query is executed, populateRecord() is called on each resulting row and checks to see that either a Model Property exists or that the column name is defined in the database schema. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#populateRecord-detail

```
class Bla extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $dist;

    //rest of your model
}
```

$model->dist should work now on instances that use your scope.

Comment: wow adding `public $dist;` worked! still dont get why tho. don't quite get the explanation in the doc. sorry new to Yii

Comment: The ActiveRecord needs a place to store the result. Unlike the column attributes of the record, which it automatically makes magic properties for, `dist` is not a property of the model, and so the assignment never happens unless you manually provide a public property.